# how to revert my app to a specific commit I made to github

Tags: git, github

I have done some stuff to my git repo and I think I am digging the hole deeper.

Right now I just want to be able to get all my current files in the state they were when I last pushed to github.  However, I do not have internet connection on that machine.  So what do I do? I do have git internally and `git log` shows that the commit I want starts with 
`c3e535f8cb.....`

I just want to revert my whole directory to that commit. is this doable with git?

right now I have nothing to commit

`git status` shows

```
# on branch master
# your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits
#  nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
git reset --hard c3e535f8cb
```

Note: you will lose changes in your repo, index and working directory since c3e535f8cb. Look into other options `--soft` `--mixed` if needed. but since you don't seem to have anything to commit ( cleand wd and index ), you can do the above. But you will lose commits. Use `git reflog` to get them back and then again use `git reset` to "reset" to those commits.

Comment: that command says `HEAD is now at C3e5e5f ...` however, when I open my files they are not the same as the files that show on github for this commit.  ok I got one commit before that and files are changed.  I am assuming that if in my last push to github, I had changed only one file and then if I do `reset --hard` it will just give me THAT file..instead of giving me ALL the files as they were in last commit.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you do a dry-run with the `--soft` option to make sure that you get the desired results.

If you don't have pushed the new changes upstream, you could easily fetch the upstream changes again, and then do a reset which suits better.

I hope that you made it through successfully with the goals that you set out to accomplish :)